# Runtime Sorting and Types with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have seen numerous articles which all seem to nibble around the issue I am having but none have provided an actual resolution to the problem. Which is to say they all get me to about 98% solution only to fail in some small detail.

I have an IEnumerable that is collected at run time. This `IEnumerable` could be of ANYTHING. I will not know until runtime. I need to sort it however based on a list of propertyNames and sort directions in a List of KeyValuePair objects provided as an argument.

```
public static void SortData(IEnumerable<dynamic> dataToSort,  List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> sortArgs)
{
}
```

I first get the Type of the `IEnumerable`. I have created a method for this. I won't get into this detail here. It's been tested and does return the proper Type.

```
public static void SortData(IEnumerable<dynamic> dataToSort, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> sortArgs)
{
    Type dataType = TypeService.GetType(data);  
}
```

I then attempt to create an initial `IOrderedEnumerable` that I can apply the `sortArgs` sort to.

```
public static void SortData(IEnumerable<dynamic> dataToSort,  List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> sortArgs)
{
    Type dataType   = TypeService.GetType(dataToSort);  

    // Create IOrderedEnumerable
    //
    var query       = from dataItem in dataToSort
                      orderby // ?????  
                      select dataItem;

    // apply sortArgs to IOrderedEnumerable
    //
    for(int argIDX = 0; argIDX < sortArgs.Count; argIDX++)
    {
        var arg             = sortArgs[argIDX];
        var sortField       = arg.Key.Trim();
        var sortDirection   = arg.Value.Trim().ToUpper();

        if(argIDX == 0)
        {
            if(sortDirection == "DESC")
            {
                query = query.OrderByDescending(e => e.GetType().GetProperty(sortField).GetValue(e));
            }
            else
            {
                query = query.OrderBy(e => e.GetType().GetProperty(sortField).GetValue(e));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(sortDirection == "DESC")
            {
                query = query.ThenByDescending(e => e.GetType().GetProperty(sortField).GetValue(e));
            }
            else
            {
                query = query.ThenBy(e => e.GetType().GetProperty(sortField).GetValue(e));
            }
        }
    }

    // After applying the sort retreive the contents
    //
    dataToSort = query.ToList();                      
}
```

It seems by this point I have all the information I should need to sort the original `dataToSort` argument. But defining a property to initialize the `IOrderedEnumerable` is eluding me.

I have tried a number of different techniques I have read about ...

```
var query       = from dataItem in dataToSort
                  orderby ( X => 1)    //ERR: The type of one of the expressions in the OrderBy clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'OrderBy'.
                  select dataItem;
```

I have tried to create a new Typed list (since I know the type) so that the expressions in the OrderBy clause could be inferred more accurately.

```
var typedDataToSort = new List<dataType>(); //ERR: dataType is a variable used like a type
foreach(var item in dataToSort)
{
    typedDataToSort.Add( item );
}
```

I have tried to get the PropertyInfo for a property to sort on..

```
PropertyInfo propInfo = dataType.GetProperty(dataValueField);
var query             = from dataItem in dataToSort
                        orderby (x => propInfo.GetValue(x, null)) //ERR: The type of one of the expressions in the OrderBy clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'OrderBy'. Of couse this could not work since `dataType` is an INSTANCE of
                        select dataItem;
```

I have just run out of ideas.

Comment: What's the reason that you use `dynamic` instead of `object` for?
`Type dataType   = TypeService.GetType(dataToSort);` Only gives you a type based on the whole list when you say there can be objects of any type?

Comment: The argument could have been a `List<KeyValuePair>` which was a value type and not an reference type. This broke the `IEnumerable<object>` type. Not sure if this is still the case (passing value types) but ...

Comment: So do all objects you pass in the list have the same property or by what do you want to sort?

Comment: The `TypeService.GetType()` returns the underlying of `dynamic`. So if `IEnumerable.<dynamic> dataSort` turned out to be a `IEnumerable<Person>' at runtime `TypeService.GetType(dataToSort)` would return `Type dataType = Person`.

Comment: The list of objects could be anything with any property names. I use reflection to validate (I omitted from the OP to reduce clutter) that the field names defined in `sortArgs` are valid for the Type returned by the `TypeService.GetType()` method.

Comment: So I should know for certain that the value of `sortField` is indeed a valid property of `dataType`.

Comment: Try something like `var query = dataToSort.OrderBy(a => 1);` This will return a `IOrderedEnumerable` with a noop sort

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233756/discussion-between-dominik-and-gary-o-stenstrom).

Comment: I tried that (the first attempt listed) . It failed compilation with the error `The type of one of the expressions in the OrderBy clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'OrderBy'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an `IOrderedIEnumerable` from a `List<T>` without manipulating the order you can just execute a noop sort by doing something like this:

```
var myList = new List<String>(){"test1", "test3", "test2"}
IOrderedIEnumerable<String> query = myList.OrderBy(x => 1);
```

The same goes for an `IEnumerable` - however you must ensure that the underlaying type of `IEnumerable` provides stable order for each iteration.

Comment: I would only add also that if you are NOT using the method Syntax it would look like ...  `from dataItem in dataToSort orderby 1  select dataItem;`
Thanks Dominik for all the help!